# How to setup Shopware 6 production environment running on docker in Ubuntu Image EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, shopware6

I would like to setup production environment on EC2 Ubuntu Image. What is the best practice for setting up production environment on a cloud server?
What are the aws services to look at apart from ec2 for the best approach?
p.s I managed to get running installation for development environment with docker on EC2 but cant find production related resources. I would like to learn more about it but could not find a relevant guide for it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's a general guide for [cluster setups with Shopware](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/installation-updates/cluster-setup). I assume that is your goal. Also if you managed to install the development template you should not run into any problems installing the [production template](https://github.com/shopware/production) in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official shopware production docker image now.

https://github.com/shopware/docker